# How do I bypass cart and go straight to checkout?

Tags: 8, commerce, rules

I know that you can easily achieve this functionality in Drupal 7 with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module or using the [Commerce Checkout Express](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_express_checkout) module.

Since Rules and Commerce are not that much integrated yet, I am not sure we can achieve this that easily, in Drupal 8.

Can I implement this feature using just rules? If the answer is *no*, how can I do it, programmatically?

Comment: It's certainly easy to achieve, but the qualifying question in response is what have you already researched / tried that didn't work?

Comment: @RyanSzrama Thanks for your interest Ryan, So far I tried using Rules with the event of "When a new order is saved" which didn't really work, tried to listen with event dispatcher when the item is added to cart but I failed miserably, and I googled around and found pretty much no solution for this

Comment: I pinged mglaman and apparently we have an open issue to support this in the queue; I don't have it handy, but I'm hoping he can kick us a link. : P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the last development version of commerce, and look for file `commerce\modules\cart\src\Form\AddToCartForm.php` which lives under the `Drupal\commerce_cart\Form` namespace, you can see that cart_id was set, and it is the order ID too.

```
$form_state->set('cart_id', $cart->id());
```

Therefore, in `hook_form_alter()`, we can get the order ID (the cart ID).

```
$order_id = $form_state->get('cart_id');
```

The complete code would be this.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function <MY_MODULE>_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    // Add to cart form id for product 5 is: commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_commerce_product_5
    // Then it's enough to check $form_id contains the string 'commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_commerce'
    if(strpos($form_id, 'commerce_order_item_add_to_cart_form_commerce') !== false) {
        $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_redirect_to_checkout';
    }
}

// Callback for form submission
// @see hook_form_alter().
function _redirect_to_checkout(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $cart_id */
  $cart_id = $form_state->get('cart_id');

  $url = Url::fromRoute('commerce_checkout.form',
    ['commerce_order' => $cart_id]
  );

  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
}
```

Comment: `$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);` requires a Url object not a string. See the [ref docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirectUrl/8.2.x) for the function.

Comment: When using this code, I get a "Error: Call to a member function getPlugin() on null in /modules/contrib/commerce/modules/payment/src/PaymentListBuilder.php on line 90" when navigating on my order edit page and clicking on Payment, it seems that this redirection breaks thie payment reference on the order...